# JavaScriptでnoUiSliderの値をCookieに保存するにあたってコードを軽量化したい。

Tags: javascript

`noUiSlider`の値を`noUiSlider.get()`で取得するのですが、その取得した値をCookieに保存する際に複数のスライダーが存在する場合、どうしても記述が長くなってしまうのですが、これを軽量化することは可能でしょうか？

### HTML

```
<div id="SuperSlider_D1" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="SuperSlider_D2" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="SuperSlider_D3" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="SuperSlider_D4" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="SuperSlider_D5" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="HogeMaster_D1" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="HogeMaster_D2" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="HogeMaster_D3" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="HogeMaster_D4" class="noUiSlider"></div>
<div id="HogeMaster_D5" class="noUiSlider"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
document.cookie = "Slider_Save=\
SuperSlider_D1_Min=" + SuperSlider_D1.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
SuperSlider_D1_Max=" + SuperSlider_D1.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
SuperSlider_D2_Min=" + SuperSlider_D2.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
SuperSlider_D2_Max=" + SuperSlider_D2.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
SuperSlider_D3_Min=" + SuperSlider_D3.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
SuperSlider_D3_Max=" + SuperSlider_D3.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
SuperSlider_D4_Min=" + SuperSlider_D4.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
SuperSlider_D4_Max=" + SuperSlider_D4.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
SuperSlider_D5_Min=" + SuperSlider_D5.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
SuperSlider_D5_Max=" + SuperSlider_D5.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
HogeMaster_D1_Min=" + HogeMaster_D1.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
HogeMaster_D1_Max=" + HogeMaster_D1.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
HogeMaster_D2_Min=" + HogeMaster_D2.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
HogeMaster_D2_Max=" + HogeMaster_D2.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
HogeMaster_D3_Min=" + HogeMaster_D3.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
HogeMaster_D3_Max=" + HogeMaster_D3.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
HogeMaster_D4_Min=" + HogeMaster_D4.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
HogeMaster_D4_Max=" + HogeMaster_D4.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
HogeMaster_D5_Min=" + HogeMaster_D5.noUiSlider.get()[0] + "/\
HogeMaster_D5_Max=" + HogeMaster_D5.noUiSlider.get()[1] + "/\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()`を使って、全ての`noUiSlider`を一気に取れる

```
let sliderSave = [...document.getElementsByClassName("noUiSlider")].map(slider=>{
  let [min,max] = slider.noUiSlider.get();
  return `${slider.id}_Min=${min}/${slider.id}_Max=${max}`;
}).join("/");

document.cookie = "Slider_Save=" + sliderSave;
```